# Is there any way to reduce the verbosity of ExtJS

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, extjs, extjs4.1

ExtJS is more verbose than jQuery, it makes you write more to do something compared to jQuery. I know that we should not compare jQuery with ExtJS but as ExtJS is a most complete Javascript UI framework while jQuery is library. But after working with jQuery for quite some time it looks like our productivity get reduced when we move to ExtJS.

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        ...
```

Can't we save some keystrokes here? Same goes for creating a textbox in form and other components.

**EDIT**

**@Verbose Code:**

```
function createPanel(){
    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            itemId: 'mainTabPanel',
            flex: 1,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Users',
                id: 'usersPanel',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                tbar: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Edit',
                    itemId: 'editButton'
                }],
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'form',
                    border: 0,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Name',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Email',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }],
                    buttons: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Save',
                        action: 'saveUser'
                    }]
                }, {
                    xtype: 'grid',
                    flex: 1,
                    border: 0,
                    columns: [{
                        header: 'Name',
                        dataIndex: 'Name',
                        flex: 1
                    }, {
                        header: 'Email',
                        dataIndex: 'Email'
                    }],
                    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
                        fields: ['Name', 'Email'],
                        data: [{
                            Name: 'Indian One',
                            Email: 'one@qinfo.com'
                        }, {
                            Name: 'American One',
                            Email: 'aone@info.com'
                        }]
                    })
                }]
            }]
        },{
            xtype: 'component',
            itemId: 'footerComponent',
            html: 'Footer Information',
            extraOptions: {
                option1: 'test',
                option2: 'test'
            },
            height: 40
        }]
    });
}
```

**@Compact Code**

```
// Main global object holding
var q = {
    // config object templates
    t: {
        layout: function(args) {
            args = args || {};
            var o = {};
            o.type = args.type || 'vbox';
            o.align = args.align || 'stretch';
            return o;
        },
        panel: function(args) {
            args = args || {};
            var o = {};
            o.xtype = 'panel';
            o.title = args.title || null;
            o.id = args.id || null;
            o.height = args.height || null;
            o.width = args.width || null;
            o.renderTo = args.renderTo || null;
            o.tbar = args.tbar || null;
            o.layout = args.layout || q.t.layout();
            o.items = args.items || [];
            return o;
        },
        button: function(text, args) {
            args = args || {};
            var o = {};
            o.xtype = 'button';
            o.text = text;
            o.itemId = args.itemId;
            return o;
        },
        tabPanel: function(args) {
            args = args || {};
            var o = {};
            o.xtype = 'tabpanel';
            o.itemId = args.itemId;
            o.flex = args.flex;
            o.layout = args.layout;
            o.tbar = args.tbar;
            o.items = args.items || [];
            return o;
        },
        form: function(args) {
            args = args || {};
            var o = {};
            o.xtype = 'form';
            o.border = args.border || 0;
            o.items = args.items || [];
            o.buttons = args.buttons || [];
            return o;
        },
        grid: function(args) {
            args = args || {};
            var o = {};
            o.xtype = 'grid';
            o.flex = args.flex || 1;
            o.border = args.border || 0;
            o.columns = args.columns || [];
            o.store = args.store || null;
            return o;
        },
        gColumn: function(header, dataIndex, args) {
            args = args || {};
            var o = {};
            o.header = header;
            o.dataIndex = dataIndex;
            o.flex = args.flex || undefined;
            return o;
        },
        fTextBox: function(label, optional, args) {
            args = args || {};
            var o = {};
            o.xtype = 'textfield';
            o.fieldLabel = label;
            o.allowBlank = optional || true;
            return o;
        },
        component: function(args) {
            args = args || {};
            var o = {};
            o.xtype = 'component';
            o.itemId = args.itemId;
            o.html = args.html;
            o.extraOptions = args.extraOptions;
            return o;
        }
    },

    // Helper methods for shortening Ext.create for containers.
    h: {
        panel: function(args) {
            return Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',
            args);
        }
    }
};
function createPanel(){
    var panel = q.h.panel({
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: q.t.panel(),
        items: [q.t.tabPanel({
            itemId: 'mainTabPanel',
            items: [q.t.panel({
                title: 'Users',
                id: 'usersPanel',
                tbar: [
                    q.t.button('Edit',{itemId: 'editButton'})
                ],
                items: [
                    q.t.form({
                        items: [ q.t.fTextBox('Name') , q.t.fTextBox('Email')],
                        buttons: [ q.t.button('Save', {action:'saveUser'} )]
                    }),
                    q.t.grid({
                    columns: [ q.t.gColumn('Name','name'), q.t.gColumn('Email', 'email', {flex: null}) ],
                    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
                        fields: ['name', 'email'],
                        data: [{
                            name: 'Indian One',
                            email: 'one@qinfo.com'
                        }, {
                            name: 'American One',
                            email: 'aone@info.com'
                        }]
                    })
                })]
            })]
        }),
            q.t.component({
                itemId: 'footerComponent',
                html: 'Footer Information',
                extraOptions: {
                    option1: 'test',
                    option2: 'test'
                },
                height: 40
            })
        ]
    });
}
```

By going with the @Compact code, it saves about 40% in terms of number of lines for example function here which is "createPanel". I wanted everyone to come up with different ideas and creating config object was one of my first idea but I wanted it to be something which I can override so I come up with above approach.

I did benchmark both the function and per Firebug (profiling feature) non-compact version takes 178ms while compact version takes 184ms.

So yes, it is going to take some more time for sure and it looks worth from this example with 8ms more but not sure when we will build an enterprise application with this approach.
Is there any better approach?, if yes please do share.

Comment: Why does your compact code have > 50 lines than the verbose code...?

Comment: as it's setting up templates (config) in a special class/methods on top of it. This way you don't have to write `xtype` every time. At the same time you can default some of the options per your application requirement. If you see carefully for some components you can save # of lines by putting params as function headers instead of javascript object. For e.g. `gColumn` has `header` and `dataIndex` as direct function param instead of args.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't need to be solved. `makeColumn('index', 'text')` against `{dataIndex: 'index', text: 'text'}`. What's the problem?

Comment: Actually I am trying to solve 2 problems here: 1) Why should I type `xtype` every time? and if some of the options are going to be 70% of time same than I can put then in a separate place and no need to write them for 70% of time. Thus saving some good amount of keystrokes.  2) I am taking control centrally here, so if I want to make some change in let us say border from 0 to 1 or 1 to 2 I can do it centrally and it can be done just by making one change for all the place where it is not overridden.

Comment: This is a terrible approach at a problem that doesn't exist.  Please don't try to do this.

Comment: You're just going to confuse other people who program with you by masking what's really going on.  Don't complicate something that's not a problem to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not really needed use xtypes:

```
{
   xtype: 'panel',
   height: 500,
   width: 500,
   renderTo: Ext.getBody()
}
```

or create yourself default configs

```
var panelCfg = {
   height: 500,
   width: 500,
   renderTo: Ext.getBody()
}
```

and apply the with ExtApplyIf

```
Ext.ApplyIf({xtype:'panel'}, panelCfg);
```

or to get a instance

```
Ext.widget('panel', panelCfg);
```

And there are still more ways.

You will definitive need to write yourself some struct and/or helpers which encapsulates your default configurations or even directly inherit your own classes from existing ones.

Comment: really appreciate your help. Can you look at updated question and share if you have some other or better ways.

Comment: @Dharmavir You are doing it the wrong way. While developing your code should be readable. For production use the Sencha Tool or any other minifier but don't program sort of minified. I guess the Compact mode is from the designer? Well, it is obvious that the compact mode will run longer. You cannot shorten your code for a tiny application cause if want a height you have to set it, same for any other property. But you can write nifty helper, plugins and extensions but it depends on each implementation. For example if can define default bahaviors for a form but I always have to add all fields.

Comment: @Dharmavir At least you can write yourself helper for nearly everything but as always this will take some more time to execute. There is definitive one point; you have to know the framework quite well, meaning not only the API, you have to read the source behind. That will bring you into a position to really shorten AND fasten your code. But I am sorry, I can'T give you a advice that would cover all cause each variant has a pro and a con. You have to conside them each time. Like the `defaults` spare lines but are a additional call + iteration. And that is a easy example.

Comment: I understand that it's always execution-time vs development-time or shorter-code. No code is from webstorm as of now and we are going to use eclipse for production. I just wanted to know if someone has already invented better way than I don't need to reinvent the wheel. One question though, do you find anything wrong with my implementation in terms of the way of doing? I am not asking about short variable names here.

Comment: I'm not sure I see any real benefit, in the long run, to what you're trying to do. As @sra pointed out, you *should* be compiling your app for production anyway, so this makes the execution time differences meaningless (and they are meaningless in dev). If you're not compiling/minifying for production, you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

In addition from what sra said, nothing stops you from creating a few short-hand methods.

Using simple generating functions with extending/mixing configs helps quite a lot.